# Scala recursive val function inside val

Tags: scala, function, recursion, nested, lazy-evaluation

Could someone explain to me what is going on?

Here I have val in which I define val function and call it right after. It ends up with error on calling `factorial(x - 1)`:

forward reference extends over definition of value factorial

```
val factorialOf3: Int = {
      val factorial: Int => Int = (x: Int) => if(x == 0) 1 else x * factorial(x - 1)
      
      factorial(3)
    }
```

If I use lazy val or def function on `factorial` definition it will compile with out error. I understand difference between lazy and eager loading but it doesn't make sense for me that it didn't work. Defining

```
val factorial: Int => Int = (x: Int) => if(x == 0) 1 else x * factorial(x - 1)
```

with out nesting it in val works fine. So why nesting it in val throws error and changing it to lazy loading or def definition fixes the problem?

Comment: For a `val` to be recursive it needs to be `lazy`, otherwise the inner reference to it is a `null`. I am not sure whenever this is a language specification or a problems with the runtime. I personally would recommend using a `def` instead.

Comment: My point is why it is happening, I would like to understand why def and lazy loading solve the problem and why nesting causes error. I am not seeing explanation why nested val recursion must be lazy.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with nesting, but what is happening is what I told you, if the value is not lazy then it can not refer to itself because it doesn't exists yet. A lazy val solves the problem because it doesn't have to exists yet, and a def solves the problems because a method is not a value is just a label in the byte code.

Comment: Interesting side note: `val factorial:...` won't compile inside _any_ `{`braced bloc`}`. The braces could define a `val`, or a `def`, or even an `if`...`else`... branch. The only exception, the only place where `val factorial:...` will compile and run is inside an `object{`block`}`.

Comment: @jwvh exactly, that's what I meant, outside brackets it compiles fine and you can refer to val itself, the problem appears when you will nest it.

Comment: But still I want to know why it is happening :D?

Comment: This is explicitly mentioned in spec (though still without explanation of why it has to be this way): "However, there is a restriction on forward references in blocks: In a statement sequence 1… making up a block, if a simple name in  refers to an entity defined by  where ≥, then for all  between and including  and ,

 cannot be a variable definition.
If  is a value definition, it must be lazy.
"
https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html

Comment: @jwvh objects `vals` are lazy, in the sense that the whole object is not loaded until needed, maybe that is the reason it works there. But, I would be sure that it just compiles but crashes with a NPE.